# Managing Magento themes with individual git repos

Tags: git, magento

My team is looking into moving multiple ecommerce sites into one Magento install. There is the potential for this to grow to dozens of sites within the single install. Because of this, we'd like to keep each individual site theme in it's own git repo. The size of the themes isn't really a concern, but we would like to be able to develop and deploy each site theme independently of the others.

I'm fairly new to magento, but my understanding is that the theme files exist across at least two directories in different locations. My first thought here would be to clone the theme into it's own folder and symlink the directories to the correct places. Are there any best practices for doing this sort of thing or any possible concerns in doing it this way?

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Comment: Great suggestion. I haven't seen that before. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is the best place for this right now though, until the area51 site is approved.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at modman - https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman